# Area calculation of an object without coordinates

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, georeferencing, area

I have a photo of an object with a scale and I want to calculate its area. I guess I have to create a polygon of the area to be calculated to use the 'field calculator'. But how do I tell the program what a centimeter (cm) is?

Comment: What GIS software are you using?

Comment: Is 'cm' centimeter?

Comment: How accurate does it need to be?

Comment: @PolyGeo I am using QGIS.

Comment: @artwork21 Yes, cm is centimeter

Comment: @MarkC  It has to be quite accurate. It is to perform comparisons between groups of objects with a few square centimeters.

Comment: Is this an aerial image? If it is, the pixilation will probably limit the accuracy, depending on the height the photo was taken. I am assuming it is something like that since this is a GIS Q&A Site and you mention Qgis. Perhaps a little more information might help in terms of where the images came from and how you arrived at a scale.

Comment: @MarkC It is an image of an extended wing with a ruler as scale, and I want to know its area. I guess the software purposed by Barrett does the job, but it is possible in Qgis, right?

Comment: The only way I could see to do it with QGis would be to use an "Arbitrary" Coordinate System, Import the image to QGis, geo- reference the corners of the photo maybe in UTM , draw a polygon, get the area and then convert the area based on the scale you georeferenced it to. I won't post this as an answer, as I do not know if it will work.

Comment: Edited my answer to add a 'gis' element to it.

Comment: @Mark C Your workflow should work just fine. In fact, with some care (by placing multiple control points in suitable locations) you can detect and correct nonlinearities in the image (which are to be *expected* due to perspective distortions).  This is why people routinely place coins instead of (or with) rulers in photos: they provide scale info in *two* dimensions, not just one, and this is critical. Even better might be to use multiple photos of the object and create a "DEM" from stereo pairs, so you can adjust the area calculation to be correct in three dimensions.

Comment: Good One @Barrett that will work. Giving you an Up Vote.

Comment: @whuber was going to give it a try but ran out of time. {Camilo Carneiro} please let us know how you go. {Barrett's} link  referenced using a coin instead of a ruler for the depth as well.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a non-GIS option which should work unless the image is georectified:

With the AnalyzingDigitalImages software you first measure the scale on your photo, then you can measure features within the photo and it calculates the area using the scale.

[Workflow - PDF](http://umassk12.net/ipy/materials/2008Summer/Pickle/Measurement.pdf)

[Digital Earth Watch Software link](http://dew.globalsystemsscience.org/software)

---

If you are focused on using GIS:

Georeference control point 1 at the beginning of your scale bar and set dstX & dstY to 0

Georeference control point 2 at the end of the scale bar and set dstX to the scale length (1200ft, 300m, etc), dstY to 0. (Also, manually edit srcY to match control point 1 srcY)

That should scale your photo to match the scale bar. Use the measuring tool to check.

Reference [GIS: Imaginary Plane World](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20158/using-qgis-for-an-imaginary-plane-world) for coordinate system info.